# JS calculating distance mouse travelled on clicks

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, events, mousedown

I am trying to calculate the distance that is recorded when the user clicks and stop the recording once the user has clicked again. How can i do this? As i am not very familiar with the mouse events I have tried using the click event but each time I click i stop the function altogether. I have the following code below.

```
var xTravelled = 0, yTravelled = 0, prevX, prevY, count = 0, select = false;
$(document).on({
    click : function(e) {
        select = true;
    },
    mousemove : function(e) {
        if (select) {
            prevY && (yTravelled += Math.abs(e.pageY - prevY));
            prevX && (xTravelled += Math.abs(e.pageX - prevX));

            prevX = e.pageX;
            prevY = e.pageY;

            $('#result').text(yTravelled + xTravelled);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Is the `var` on the first line a typo?

Comment: It is! Sorry about that!

Comment: You might want to use [pythagoras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem) to calculate the distance instead of just adding the x and y distances.

Comment: Indeed! I am using pythagoras to calculate the distance. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your

```
 click : function(e) {
        select = (select==false)?true:false;

    },
```

here the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dyvqkk8j/)